# Conditionally remove CDATA from XML using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

I have an XML as below.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ns1:EnvioCFE xmlns:ns1="http://tempuri.org/">
    <ns1:name>erp</ns1:name>
    <ns1:cfexml>
        <![CDATA[<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
        <n0:CFE_Adenda xmlns:n0="http://cfe.dgi.gub.uy">
            <n0:CFE version="1.0">
                <n0:eTck>
                    <n0:Encabezado>
                        <n0:IdDoc>
                            <n0:TipoCFE>101</n0:TipoCFE>
                            <n0:Serie/>
                            <n0:Nro/>
                            <n0:NroInterno>286412030000002022</n0:NroInterno>
                            <n0:FchEmis>2022-07-22</n0:FchEmis>
                            <n0:MntBruto>1</n0:MntBruto>
                            <n0:FmaPago>2</n0:FmaPago>
                            <n0:FchVenc>2022-07-24</n0:FchVenc>
                        </n0:IdDoc>
                        </n0:Encabezado>
                  </n0:eTck>
            </n0:CFE>
            <n0:Adenda>
                <n0:Texto>
                    <![CDATA[&lt;p&gt;Please remit funds to :&lt;/p&gt;&lt;p&gt;Bank:JPMORGAN CHASE BANK, NA&lt;/p&gt;&lt;p&gt;Account:783063321&lt;/p&gt;&lt;p&gt;Beneficiary:COFCO International Uruguay Overseas SA&lt;/p&gt;&lt;p&gt;SWIFT:CHASUS33&lt;/p&gt;]]>
                </n0:Texto>
            </n0:Adenda>
        </n0:CFE_Adenda>]]></ns1:cfexml>
    <ns1:reference>000d3aabbc3c1eed8fae8ce273e99c15</ns1:reference>
</ns1:EnvioCFE>
```

I need to remove the CDATA specifically under the Texto field and pass the value as is.

I am trying to perform the below XSLT version 1.0 but it is giving me a blank output.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ns0:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:n0="http://tempuri.org/" xmlns:ns0="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
   <ns0:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"/>
   <ns0:strip-space elements="*"/>
   <ns0:template match="@*|node()">
      <ns0:copy>
         <ns0:apply-templates select="ns0:Texto"/>
      </ns0:copy>
   </ns0:template>
</ns0:stylesheet>
```

Can someone help here?

Also occasionally the Texto fields come without CDATA but with similar contents. In those cases the data is passed to the target as expected.

Expected result:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ns1:EnvioCFE xmlns:ns1="http://tempuri.org/">
    <ns1:name>erp</ns1:name>
    <ns1:cfexml>
        <![CDATA[<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
        <n0:CFE_Adenda xmlns:n0="http://cfe.dgi.gub.uy">
            <n0:CFE version="1.0">
                <n0:eTck>
                    <n0:Encabezado>
                        <n0:IdDoc>
                            <n0:TipoCFE>101</n0:TipoCFE>
                            <n0:Serie/>
                            <n0:Nro/>
                            <n0:NroInterno>286412030000002022</n0:NroInterno>
                            <n0:FchEmis>2022-07-22</n0:FchEmis>
                            <n0:MntBruto>1</n0:MntBruto>
                            <n0:FmaPago>2</n0:FmaPago>
                            <n0:FchVenc>2022-07-24</n0:FchVenc>
                        </n0:IdDoc>
                        </n0:Encabezado>
                  </n0:eTck>
            </n0:CFE>
            <n0:Adenda>
                <n0:Texto>&lt;p&gt;Please remit funds to :&lt;/p&gt;&lt;p&gt;Bank:JPMORGAN CHASE BANK, NA&lt;/p&gt;&lt;p&gt;Account:783063321&lt;/p&gt;&lt;p&gt;Beneficiary:COFCO International Uruguay Overseas SA&lt;/p&gt;&lt;p&gt;SWIFT:CHASUS33&lt;/p&gt;>
                </n0:Texto>
            </n0:Adenda>
        </n0:CFE_Adenda>]]></ns1:cfexml>
    <ns1:reference>000d3aabbc3c1eed8fae8ce273e99c15</ns1:reference>
</ns1:EnvioCFE>
```

Comment: Please edit your question and add the exact result you expect to get.

Comment: And also fix your input example - currently it produces an error.

Answer (score 1):

First, understand that a CDATA section (as far as XSLT is concerned) is just a text node. In your case the text node contains lexical XML. It doesn't contain a node tree, therefore it doesn't contain any elements named `Texto`, therefore your apply-templates won't select anything.

To turn the lexical XML into a node tree you have to parse it. In XSLT 3.0 that can be done using the parse-xml() function. In earlier versions there's no standard way of doing it; you may need vendor or user-written extension functions, or you may need to run multiple transformations in a pipeline.

In fact the content of your (wannabe) `Texto` element is pretty weird, because it's not only in CDATA, it also contains escaped markup (or what would be escaped markup if it were not in CDATA). So your first level of XML parsing gives you the CDATA section as a text node, your next level of XML parsing gives you a node-tree containing a `Texto` element, and you need a third level of parsing to extract the escaped `p` element within that.

There's something badly wrong with the design of this XML, but it's up to you whether to try and improve the design, or to write code that untangles the mess you've been presented with.